# Understanding an Implicit Instantiation of Class Template Specialization Example

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, declaration, definition, template-specialization

So [this section](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2) of the standard gives this example (My questions are inline):

```
template<class T, class U>
struct Outer {
    template<class X, class Y> struct Inner;      // Where are X and Y from? Is this defining a struct?
    template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y>;         // Is this defining a struct specialization? If so what is Y?
    template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y> { };     // I feel like this is a redefinition of the line above, could it ever not be?
    template<class Y> struct Inner<U, Y> { };
};
```

Admittedly I can't understand the linked section of the standard cause I can't understand what's happening here. I think I'm just getting confused by all the `template`s flying around, but If someone could just go line by line and tell me what's happening that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Downvoter I know this was tagged C++. Were you just providing the mandatory downvote on C++ questions, or was there actually something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> template<class X, class Y> struct Inner;      
> // Where are X and Y from? Is this defining a struct?
> ```

This is the declaration of template struct `Inner`, `X` and `Y` is the template parameters.

> ```
> template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y>;         
> // Is this defining a struct specialization? If so what is Y?
> ```

This is the declaration of a partial specialization, `Y` is the template parameter.

> ```
> template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y> { };     
> // I feel like this is a redefinition of the line above, could it ever not be?
> ```

This is the definition of the partial specialization, so no redefinition here.

Then use them as:

```
Outer<foo1, foo2>::Inner<foo3, foo4>* i1; 
// the primary template is used, with T=foo1, U=foo2, X=foo3, Y=foo4
// btw the primary template is not defined in this example

Outer<foo1, foo2>::Inner<foo1, foo3> i2; 
// the 1st partial specialization is used, with T=foo1, U=foo2, Y=foo3

Outer<foo1, foo2>::Inner<foo2, foo3> i3; 
// the 2st partial specialization is used, with T=foo1, U=foo2, Y=foo3
```

Comment: Can we actually do: `Outer<foo1, foo2>::Inner<foo3, foo4> i1;`? Is that defined?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct Outer {
    // Forward-declares a struct with two template parameters
    template<class X, class Y> struct Inner;

    // Forward-declares a partial specialization of Inner
    // (Y is its only template parameter)
    template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y>;

    // Defines the forward-declared partial specialization
    template<class Y> struct Inner<T, Y> { };

    // Declares and defines another partial specialization
    // (Y is its only template parameter)
    template<class Y> struct Inner<U, Y> { };
};
```